# Spring Kafka Consumer randomly skipping offsets

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Kafka and has a Kafka consumer that reads messages from a topic to process some business logic. I have noticed the listener is randomly skipping some offsets. The topic has 20 partitions and my application has 4 nodes so I have distributed the partitions by 5 threads on each node. the group name is unique and there is not consumer group with the same name in my application. Following is my Kafka Consumer

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "test", groupId = "testgroup", 
            concurrency = "5", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory", autoStartup = "true")
    public void handleMessage(@Payload String message,
                              @Header(value = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY, required = false) String messageKey,
                              @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
                              @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                              @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) String offset) {
```

Following is the Kafka Consumer setting:

```
   Map<String, Object> getConsumerProperties() {
            Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "bootstap server coordinates");
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "consumerId");
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor");
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "10000");
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG,30000);
            return config;
        }
```

I have tried setting the consumer to read_uncommitted as I was thinking it was because of transactional producer and for some reason producer is not able to commit the certain offsets but later discovered that default is "read_uncommitted" as well so no need to explicitly define that.

Comment: That makes no sense; you need to provide much more information.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell I figured out the issue; it was because Kafka Listener Container Factory was set to "Batch" and our  lister was expecting one message at a time. as we had default settings for 'max.partition.fetch.bytes' and due to large size of our message payload mostly one message/event was being picked in one poll and handed over to the Kafka Listener. The issue was noticed for the cases where poll returned 2 or more events. so as a fix we have made our Kafka factory to default i.e. ''Record' as we are not expecting batch processing in our business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue; it was because Kafka Listener Container Factory was set to "Batch" and our listner was expecting one message at a time.

```
@Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(){
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryString());
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        return factory;
    }
```

As we had default settings for 'max.partition.fetch.bytes' and due to large size of our message payload mostly one message/event was being picked in one poll and handed over to the Kafka Listener. The issue was noticed for the cases where poll returned 2 or more events. so as a fix we have made our Kafka factory to default i.e. ''Record' as we are not expecting batch processing in our business.

```
Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(){
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryString());
        return factory;
    }
```